# How to make confirm message i18n compatible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, link-to, rails-i18n

I'm relatively new to Rails, and have been programming a few months.

I'm trying to use the t() method for internationalization, but it doesn't seem to work when I ask for confirmation in a link_to.

For example, when I write

```
    <%= link_to t( ".delete_student_info"), 
       @student,
       method: :delete, 
       confirm: "child_deletion_confirmation"
    %>
```

...I predictably get a link_to that works and asks the confirmation question

However, when I write

```
    <%= link_to t( ".delete_student_info"), 
        @student,
        method: :delete, 
        confirm: t( ".child_deletion_confirmation")
    %>
```

...I get the following output

> Child Deletion Confirmation" data-method="delete" href="/en/student_profiles/41" rel="nofollow">Delete Student Info

Is there something conceptual that I am missing?  I've looked in the Rails Guides Rails i18n API, but it doesn't address this issue.  I'm thinking that maybe the confirm: is something different, but I don't know how to look it up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your specific Rails version in the tags? I assume it's Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this out on my Rails 4 console and it worked fine:

```
helper.link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/", data: { confirm: I18n.t("date.formats.default") }
# => "<a data-confirm=\"%Y-%m-%d\" href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org/\">Visit Other Site</a>"`.
```

Now, note the behavior when using `nil` for the `:confirm` is like what you're seeing:

```
helper.link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/", data: { confirm: nil }
# => "<a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org/\">Visit Other Site</a>"
```

So this makes me think that somehow your translation is evaluating to `nil`. However, I can't seem to figure out how to duplicate that issue...

I'll expand this answer to try to help more if you can show what the translations file looks like?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect Rails 4 syntax. (The `confirm` option should be part of the `data` hash now.)

Comment: Thanks.  This works perfectly!  I don't actually have anything in the translation file yet, so the confirmation I get actually says `translation missing` but that is ok...I'll add it in later.